# Unelevate PowerShell Session

Tags: powershell, uac

I have a PowerShell script that runs as Administrator, and another script it calls that needs to *not* run as Administrator.  I've used `Start-Process -FilePath "powershell.exe" -Verb runas` to elevate before, but how might I "unelevate" from a session already running as administrator?

I want to avoid third-party tools like `psexec` that [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31449633/how-can-i-make-powershell-run-a-program-as-a-standard-user) uses.  Ideally looking for a build-in PS function or PSSnapin.

The specific process requiring this "unelevated" session is seeing drives mounted by an administrator.  According to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/ee844140(v%3dws.10)) UAC is the likely culprit.  The solution proposed was running the following:
 `New-ItemProperty -Path HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System -Name EnableLinkedConnections -Value 1 -PropertyType DWord`

However, the drives still do not show up when `Get-PSDrive` runs in an elevated session.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make PowerShell run a program as a standard user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31449633/how-can-i-make-powershell-run-a-program-as-a-standard-user)

Comment: Something like: `Start-Process -FilePath "powershell.exe" -Credential <standard user creds>`

Comment: I tried this Start-Process concept but it is still running as administrator, despite the <standard user> creds.

Comment: What problem are you solving that requires this?

Comment: Trying to see a list of network drives mounted by the standard user.  However, list must be seen as part of a larger script run as administrator.  Running `mount` or `Get-PSDrive` from the administrator script does not show the expected drives.  However, the drives show up when either of those commands are run with standard privileges.

Comment: I don't think that "un-elevating" will solve your problem. User drive mappings are stored in HKCU (not HKLM), so even if you "un-elevate," you will still be running as the user that was elevated (not the logged on user).

Answer (score 2):

You could try built-in runas.exe for "unelevation" like in this answer [Batch file: Drop elevated privileges (run a command as original user)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20218076/batch-file-drop-elevated-privileges-run-a-command-as-original-user)

```
runas /trustlevel:0x20000 "YourCommandHere"
```

Comment: With a general `YourCommandHere` (e.g. "timeout 10") this technique would work.  However, my script looks at mapped network drives using `Get-PSDrive` (or the `mount` cmd.exe equivalent).  I created a .bat file (that runs `mount`) for "YourCommandHere" but it did not show the expected drives.

Comment: It seems that your issue is not about "unelevation". Have you seen this https://superuser.com/questions/199387/elevated-command-line-prompt-cant-access-shared-drives ?

Comment: Similar issue, but I need to avoid mapping the shared drives again (just testing the mounting for the "unelevated" user succeeded).  Interesting [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/ee844140(v%3dws.10)) linked from that post with Microsoft's proposed solution.  I tried creating a new registry key in 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System` of `EnableLinkedConnections` as suggested in that article - but hasn't improved results yet.

Comment: IIRC, `EnableLinkedConnections` requires a reboot to take effect. But as I noted previously, I don't think this solves your problem anyway because mapped drives are per-user.