# Run bat file at lower privilege level

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a script which has to run from an administrator level powershell/cmd prompt
Why? Because it has to use logman to get windows counters
Problem: The software for which I want to log the windows counters for has to be started with regular user level rights.
I've seen that there are lots of examples on how to run as Administrator
I don't see any on running as Regular User

```
Launch exe file
Start Logman (Admin level)
Run Bat File to Open Program
Bat File should run with regular user level priv's
```

I had a look at using RUNAS but that requires password entry, which I don't want.
Is there some other way on windows to delevate?

Comment: There is [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53727582/). So use this command in your batch-file: `runas /trustlevel:0x20000 "%~f0"`. Where `"%~f0"` is the file-path of your batch. Can be replaced with `"logman.exe"` or any other command.

Comment: Thank you for this. I'm afraid that I didn't think to search on unelevate. I will try it now.

Answer (score 0):

you could use psexec

psexec -l powershell.exe -executionpolicy unrestricted -noexit -file c:\temp\checkelevated.ps1

-l : Run process as limited user (strips the Administrators group and allows only privileges assigned to the Users group). On Windows Vista the process runs with Low Integrity.